# How to Know the requesting IP with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, connection, ip

I have created a Google Apps Script to import data from Database(RDS/AWS) to Google Spreadsheet.
Then I created a trigger to execute the script, however, I keep getting connection errors.
But it's completed successfully when I execute the specific method on Google Apps Script.

Now I want to know if it's because the requesting IP are different between when running by a trigger and hands.
**How can I know the requesting IP when I execute it with hands and also when the script's run automatically by a trigger?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will works ( Calling an external API ),

```
function getIP() {
  var url = "http://api.ipify.org";
  var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know it.

You must check if the script is running too many times in a day, because some servers could block the access.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [related thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2569), you cannot know the request IP in Google Apps Script. You can also log a request for this feature as stated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643277/google-apps-script-get-ip-of-dopost-and-track-in-spreadsheet).

Check these links:

- [Google App Scripts get IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864424/google-app-scripts-get-ip)
- [Determining the IP address of the node that executes the UrlFetchApp call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708477/determining-the-ip-address-of-the-node-that-executes-the-urlfetchapp-call)